# Set preference of profile before startup

Tags: firefox-addon

I am trying to set the preference of a profile before it starts up. So like by modifying or writing some file. Is this possible?

I am also creating a new empty profile and want its first start to be with certain prefs set, is this possible? I feel both questions very related.

Specifically I am trying to add a preference of `taskbar.grouping.useprofile` with value of `true`. As setting this preference requires a restart and there are some other benefits which I can get into if you are curious (its some deep/complex stuff with how Win7+ iconing/grouping/jumplisting in taskbar etc work).

Comment: Have you considered manipulating prefs.js in the profile directory.

Comment: Thanks @the8472 I dont understand this file. What do the things in there do? Can I create this file for a totally brand new profile? Like on profile create its just an empty folder, if I throw in a prefs.js in there with `user_pref("taskbar.grouping.useprofile", true);` will it take? Just asking if you know Ill definitely get around to testing this some time in next couple days.